# Layer Symbology Changes when importing ArcMap into ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-pro, symbology

I noticed that my symbols changed slightly when I imported from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro. I didn't find this documented anywhere. The layer is a polyline with a referenced style symbol. ArcGIS Pro imported layer but the line weights are all different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a BUG, but you can try to save the symbology as a layer file in ArcMap and import it in Pro, also check this https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/arcgis-pro-quot-export-map-styles-quot-for-bulk/idi-p/937605.

Comment: Thank you Yogesh.